# 32bit-64bit Installer Help

Tags: 32bit-64bit, inno-setup

Looking for help to build a 32/64 bit installer.  I've looked for help here already, found some from Mithriel but unfortunately I'm very new to editing registry keys.

I replied to his answer and posted my script but a Mod removed it.  I apologize for any gap in etiquette.

I'm using InnoIDE to develop my installer.  Essentially I just want it to be able to detect the chipset architecture and then load in the appropriate registry values.

From what I understand it looks like many are creating a parent installer that runs two other installer (one for 32 and 64 respectively).  That's great but the files I will be copying to the install directory are about a GB.  I can't really have those files 
duplicated obviously.

I'm also looking for a way to delete a folder on install as well.

I can post script/email it to anyone willing to help me out.

J.

Comment: Do you actually need two installers, or can you just use a 32-bit one and let it stick your application in Program Files (x86)?

Comment: Indeed. If the application is only one "bitness" then a dual-bit installer is just waste. x64 users will be able to use an x86 installer to install an x86 application just fine. x86 users don't even need to worry about installing an x64 application.

Comment: This isn't really a question. It's a request for someone to privately email you their help. Can you rephrase this?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit on "why" there is a need for a 32/64-bit installer. This doesn't answer the question, but has evolved too large for a comment. See the other comments in the original post.

---

The "problem" with using a 32-bit installer for a 64-bit application (and vice-versa) is due to [Windows Registry Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx).

A 32-bit installer will (unless it uses special flags when writing to the registry write to the "32-bit view" of the registry and the application will see the "64-bit view"). If the application itself only runs in 32-bit then this doesn't matter and only a 32-bit installer is needed, of course. Like wise, if it only runs in 64-bit then only a 64-bit version of the installer is needed.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

while using inno setup i found a problem to writte to the 64 bits registery it seems that is differnet instruction while writting on 32 bits.
so it need more search and i will not got stocked for this.

Answer (score 0):

Without being more specific with the question, the [registry section of the documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) includes specific constants for 32- and 64-bit registry options. For example, see this section:

> The values may have a suffix of 32 or 64. Root key values with a
>   suffix of 32 (for example, HKLM32) map to the 32-bit view of the
>   registry; root key values with a suffix of 64 (for example, HKLM64)
>   map to the 64-bit view of the registry.

Make a set of registry entries for each bit-ness, and in each entry, specify the the 32- or 64-bit registry root, and add a [Check: IsWin64](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_iswin64.htm) parameter for the 64-bit registry entries. You should be able to invert that check on the 32-bit entries.